# Prevent a button click event to refresh the page

Tags: javascript, c#, html, devexpress

I need to prevent a button to refresh the page it's in. 
After the first refresh, it just works, but the first time it refreshed the page and it's really annoying.

The button click event sets a display property on "block"

I've already tried every single way suggested here.

```html
<button id="kkBtn_add" style="width:40px;" onclick="addAppointment(); return false;"">+</button>
```

edit: (removed the double ")

```html
<button id="kkBtn_add" style="width:40px;" onclick="addAppointment(); return false;">+</button>
```

```js
<script>               
        function addAppointment() {}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below code should help.

```
<input id="kkBtn_add" style="width:40px;" onclick="addAppointment(); return false;">+</input>
```

Comment: Still not working. 

I fixed the double " but for some reason, if I put type="button", I get an Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick

If i don't add the type part, it keeps refreshing the page

Comment: You might have written the function definition outside document ready. To avoid `Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined at HTMLButtonElement.onclick` error, try to define like below

`$( document ).ready(function() {
function addAppointment(){
}
}`

Answer (score 0):

Remove return from click event
add below code

```
<button id="kkBtn_add" style="width:40px;" onclick="addAppointment();">+</button>
```